# How can an IOS app access Google Drive files

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone know how if IOS apps can access files stored on Google Drive?

I did not find what I was looking for on https://developers.google.com/drive/

thanks

Andy

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995787/listing-all-folder-content-from-google-drive/18009616#18009616

Answer (score 6):

The API for Google Drive is now released for Objective C. You can find it here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive App for iOS will be release soon, is what was said in some articles. See below.

http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/04/24/google-drive-for-iphone-and-ipad-coming-soon/

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/full-sized_screenshots_of_the_google_drive_ipad_ap.php

Answer (score 1):

I think the generic Google GTL Library (Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ ) is going to include some generated code for Drive access. Drive SDK docs seem to link there but the code is still missing. Doc is also a bit inconsistent regarding iOS native apps:
"Apps will not have any API access to files unless the app has been installed in Chrome Web Store. To test an app during development, you must first create a listing and install it."

Nico.

Answer (score 0):

Yep although not directly through Objective C you would need to interface with Ruby, Python, PHP, or Java.

Here is a list of Examples: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/index

Answer (score 0):

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idocs-hd-pro-for-google-docs/id498653441?mt=8, I found this App 
can access google drive files on iPad, maybe google docs api can

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) to access files stored in Google Drive using the Documents List API.

The library also includes a complete sample: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FDocsSample

Answer (score 0):

"Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C" has been depreciated by Google and is only working for apps already on AppStore.

New Implementation for accessing Google Drive API for iOS using "Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C For REST".

Here is the working implementation for accessing Google Drive Files in iOS using "Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C For REST" library : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41649210/1999368